# Post Geocoordinates with TweetSharp on WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, twitter, tweetsharp

I am trying to add geocoordinates to Twitter posts on Windows Phone 7. The API provides a method `SendTweet(string status, double lat, double @long, Action<TwitterStatus, TwitterResponse> action)` for doing so. However, the geocoordinates are not posted and in the response, the `coordinates`field is always null. The status of the response is OK, though.

I am using version 2.1.2 of TweetSharp from the NuGet repository. I do know that there have been issued with geocoordinates before, but according to the project website these have been resolved with version 2.1.0.

To be honest, I am running out of ideas. Does anyone know the trick how one can add the coordinates? I would also be willing to

Thanks in advance,
Christoph